# Recursion Star pattern

Tags: python, recursion

I need a specific pattern of stars to print from a recursion solution. The input looks much like this:

```
printPattern(2,8)
```

and the output would be:

```
  *
  **
   *
  ****
    *
    **
     *
  ********
      *
      **
       *
      ****
        *
        **
         *
```

Yes, there are 2 spaces at the beginning already .and for printPattern(0,4):

```
*
**
 *
****
  *
  **
   *
```

I have started with what follows, but I know I'm going in the wrong direction with "repeat" any pointers on how to continue, or should I scrap it?

Right now all I've done is find out even and odd lines and I planned on printing star with repeat starting at 0, but I get an UnboundLocalError:

```
repeat = 0
def printPattern(n,k):
    'prints a pattern of stars'
    if n == k:
        print("Done")
    elif n%2 == 0:
        print('even')
        repeat +=1
        printPattern(n+1,k)
    else:
        print (end=' ')*repeat
        print ('*')
        repeat+=1
        printPattern(n+1,k)
```

Comment: Can you post what you have tried so far, and perhaps we can help you out?

Comment: questions like "i say a bunch of words to you, now you make everything" are not much useful...

Comment: pass `repeat` as a parameter to the function (otherwise you need `global repeat` at the top of the function to allow `repeat += 1` due to how name bindings and scope work in Python

Comment: Not sure how this is vague, and I gave what I have so far So not sure what else to do.

Comment: `print (end=' ')*repeat` is a TypeError (`print` returns None). Try: `print(' '*repeat, end='')`

Answer (score 0):

Most of the discussion centers on the `repeat` variable which really isn't needed, either as a global nor as a parameter.  Your termination case `n == k` seems strange as termination depends on `k` but `k` doesn't depend on `n`.  I think `k < 1` is really when this recursion stops.  Finally, your even case doesn't print anything.

I've broken this problem into three steps: recursively print a smaller pattern to the left of center; print the center; recursively print a smaller pattern offset to the right of center:

```
def printPattern(n, k):
    ''' print a pattern of stars '''

    if k < 1:  # base case
        return

    printPattern(n, k // 2)
    print(' ' * n, '*' * k, sep='')
    printPattern(n + k - k // 2, k // 2)

print(2, 8)
printPattern(2, 8)
print(0, 4)
printPattern(0, 4)
print(5, 9)
printPattern(5, 9)
```

OUTPUT

```
> python3 test.py
2 8
  *
  **
   *
  ****
    *
    **
     *
  ********
      *
      **
       *
      ****
        *
        **
         *
0 4
*
**
 *
****
  *
  **
   *
5 9
     *
     **
      *
     ****
       *
       **
        *
     *********
          *
          **
           *
          ****
            *
            **
             *
>
```

Since no example was provided, and I couldn't reverse engineer it from your code, I didn't do anything too interesting with odd number inputs.